# IBM Tivoli - Report Studio - (context) menus do not work

Tags: context-menu, redhat-enterprise-linux

The (context) menus do not work in the IBM Tivoli Report Studio.
I can open the (context) menus but they do not react by clicking on them
How can I fix this?

System:

- RedHad Linux 6.2
- Firefox 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by downgrading your Browser.

The latest officially supported Firefox is 3.6 (fix 1 or above)

See the following list for further supported browser / information https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019191

In case you don't want or cannot downgrade your browser you may consider using firefox portable (combined with wine if you work on linux and can not find a linux version)